# how prevent direct file download from browser when permission has been set [read = allow]

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, permissions, download

i have a handler for download files like below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using NiceFileExplorer.Classes;

namespace NiceFileExplorer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for HandlerForMyFE
    /// </summary>
    public class HandlerForMyFE : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
    {
        private HttpContext _context;
        private HttpContext Context
        {
            get
            {
                return _context;
            }
            set
            {
                _context = value;
            }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
            string filePath = context.Request.QueryString["Downloadpath"];
            filePath = context.Server.MapPath(filePath);

            if (filePath == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
            System.IO.BinaryReader binaryReader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(streamReader.BaseStream);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[streamReader.BaseStream.Length];

            binaryReader.Read(bytes, 0, (int)streamReader.BaseStream.Length);

            if (bytes == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            streamReader.Close();
            binaryReader.Close();

            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            string MimeType = GetMimeType(fileName);
            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filePath);
            char[] extension_ar = extension.ToCharArray();
            string extension_Without_dot = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 1; i < extension_ar.Length; i++)
            {
                extension_Without_dot += extension_ar[i];
            }

            string filesize = string.Empty;
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(filePath);
            filesize = f.Length.ToString();

            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["User_ID"] != null)
            {
                WriteFile(bytes, fileName, filesize, MimeType + " " + extension_Without_dot, context.Response);
            }

        }

        private void WriteFile(byte[] content, string fileName, string filesize, string contentType, HttpResponse response)
        {
            response.Buffer = true;
            response.Clear();

            response.ContentType = contentType;

            response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

            response.AddHeader("Content-Length", filesize);

            response.BinaryWrite(content);
            response.Flush();
            response.End();
        }

        private string GetMimeType(string fileName)
        {
            string mimeType = "application/unknown";
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
            if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
                mimeType = regKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();
            return mimeType;
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the important part of this handler is WriteFile And It works perfect!
i call this handler for download a file from code behind like below  :

```
Response.Redirect("~/Handler.ashx?Downloadpath=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DownloadPath));
```

one of my download links in my web site is like below :

```
http://localhost:5410/en/Download.aspx?Downloadpath=%2fFiles%2f%2fsamsung%2fGE2550_DEFAULT_MDL_V002.exe
```

so, i can contorl my download links easily by that handler!

my problem is when some body changes that link to :

```
http://localhost:5410/Files/samsung/GE2550_DEFAULT_MDL_V002.exe
```

`can download that file directly without that handler!`

how can i prevent this direct download?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, putting the actual physical path to the file into the querystring is not really a good idea. Gives a bit too much information to the public, and opens you to security issues with people putting unexpected paths into the url to try and download other files.

With that said, regarding you problem above, you should either put your Files folder outside of the web root so that it is inaccessible from the browser, or setup IIS so that no one is allowed access to that folder (and subfolders). As long as the account that ASP.NET runs under has permissions to the folder, you will still be able to open the file in your code and write it to the response, regardless of whether it's visible through IIS.

Comment: hi dear bro and thanks for answer! how can i invisible files from iis?

Comment: when i change the permission of Files folder, i got an error (Access to Files folder is denied)!

Comment: would you please give me some explain about way #2

Comment: What version of IIS are you running, and do you actually have access to the IIS management console, or are  you on a shared hosting account with some sort of control panel?

Comment: windows server 2008 r2 - i have a private server and have remote access to it

Comment: The first option is to move your Files folder outside of the folder your web app is in to somewhere else on the machine. You would no longer be able to use Server.Mappath to get the physical path, though, so you'd need to put the physical path in your config somewhere.

Comment: An alternative, is to disable Anonymous Access for that folder in IIS. I'm not real familiar with that version of IIS, but I think you would go into IIS Mangement Console, click on the Authentication section, and then disable Anonymous access for your Files folder (not everything).

Comment: my problem solved by first option -> i am working on option #2...howevere thanks for comments.